# Restlet POST Form to send to client resource via JSON

Tags: json, google-app-engine, post, restlet

I am getting a 415 Error when sending a form entry to another client resource via JSON.  The target URI in my code below ("/message") works when not using the form (i.e. hit "/message" with a test mock object).

Here is my code to get the values of the form and do the post to the target resource.  Am I missing something that needs to be done?

I am using the following:

- Restlet: 2.1 RC5
- GAE: 1.6.1

Form Restlet:

```
@Post
public void handlePost(Representation entity) {

    final Form webForm = new Form(entity);
    MessageEntity newMessage = new MessageEntity();

    String subject = webForm.getFirstValue("subject");
    String sendto = webForm.getFirstValue("email");
    String message = webForm.getFirstValue("message");

    newMessage.setCategoryID(subject);
    newMessage.setAccountID(sendto);
    newMessage.setMessageText(message);

    ClientResource cr = new ClientResource(getRootRef()+ "/message");
    cr.post(newMessage, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
}
```

Target Resource ("/message")

```
   @Post("json")
   public void HandleRequest(MessageEntity messageEntity) {

   // Logic here

   }
```

Please let me know if you need more information

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have code that is very similar to yours that works fine.  I am also running similar versions of Restlet and GAE.  First question I have is are there other @Post methods in your Target Resource as sometimes the ordering matters.

Here are two versions of code that I have that work....
1)

```
public Representation postHandler() {    
  Reference commitsRef = new Reference(Consts.RESOURCE_BASE + "commitments/");    
  ClientResource commitsResource = new ClientResource(getContext(), commitsRef);
  ....
  Representation commitsRep = commitsResource.post(commitForm);
```

That is posting a form to a Target resource that handles both @Post("json") and @Post("form")

2)

```
public Representation doPostFromGet() {   
  Reference takeActRef = new Reference(Consts.RESOURCE_BASE + "commitment/"
      + commitmentId + "/userActs/");     
  ClientResource takeActResource = new ClientResource(getContext(), takeActRef);
  ...
  Representation takeActRep = takeActResource.post(newAct);
```

That is posting a Java object to a form that uses what I call the "Peierls magic".  See:
http://tembrel.blogspot.com/2012/03/converting-forms-in-restlet-to-pojos.html
It allows you to have one post() in the Target and accept both forms and pojos.

On a minor note, if you are doing a post to add a new message, should the url be "/messages/" (plural) - and perhaps there is a typo somewhere?  (An unlikely possibility, but I thought I would mention it).

Good luck,

RB